# Android 6.0 Do-not-Disturb: how to go to vibrate only in certain hours?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, silent-mode, nexus-6p

I'm trying to familarize myself with my newest Nexus 6p, which runs Android 6.0.1 now.

Do I understand correctly, that currently Do-not-Disturb cannot manipulate calls and notifications volume so that I could set it to go to "Vibrate only" during hours I am in the office?

If not, what is the appropriate method to achieve this? External app only?

**ADDED 13.05.2016**
I solved the problem via [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=ru).

Comment: If you want your app to do it automatically try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=tr)

Comment: Can you explain the question in bit different words? I may be able to help out.

Comment: Firelord - my understanding is OP is asking whether "do not disturb" can be configured to permit vibration or whether it will always disable it.

Comment: If you could find the time to write up what you did with Tasker to achieve your goal, it would be really helpful to other visitors with the same problem. Helping each other is what we're all here for.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Do-not-Disturb cannot manipulate calls and notifications volume.

I think the only way to go to "vibrate only" is to hold volume down key all the way down. But you also need to turn the volume up manually.